# InternalsVisibleTo attribute ignored when compiling solution via Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

So I am developing a Roslyn-based frontend compiler that parses a C# solution, performs rewriting on the syntax trees to desugar some constructs of my DSL, and then uses the Roslyn APIs to compile and emit executables/dlls. This last part, given a compilation, is done very simply like this (some details omitted for clarity):

```
var compilation = project.GetCompilationAsync().Result;

var compilationOptions = new CSharpCompilationOptions(outputKind,
  compilation.Options.ModuleName, compilation.Options.MainTypeName,
  compilation.Options.ScriptClassName, null,
  compilation.Options.OptimizationLevel, compilation.Options.CheckOverflow, 
  false, compilation.Options.CryptoKeyContainer, 
  compilation.Options.CryptoKeyFile, compilation.Options.CryptoPublicKey, 
  compilation.Options.DelaySign, Platform.AnyCpu, 
  compilation.Options.GeneralDiagnosticOption, 
  compilation.Options.WarningLevel,
  compilation.Options.SpecificDiagnosticOptions,
  compilation.Options.ConcurrentBuild, 
  compilation.Options.XmlReferenceResolver,
  compilation.Options.SourceReferenceResolver,
  compilation.Options.MetadataReferenceResolver,
  compilation.Options.AssemblyIdentityComparer,
  compilation.Options.StrongNameProvider);

var targetCompilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(assemblyFileName,
  compilation.SyntaxTrees, compilation.References,
  compilationOptions);

EmitResult emitResult = null;
using (var outputFile = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
  emitResult = targetCompilation.Emit(outputFile);
  if (emitResult.Success)
  {
    return fileName;
  }
}
```

So everything works perfectly fine, until I tried to compile a solution where a project A declares some internal classes/fields, and then uses the `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("...")]` attribute (in the AssemblyInfo.cs file) to give visibility of these internals to another project B.

Directly compiling using visual studio works perfectly fine and allows B to see these internal declarations of A. However, when I try to compile through my tool using the Roslyn APIs, it is like the InternalsVisibleTo attribute is completely ignored, and I am getting back errors, such as:

`error CS0122: ... is inaccessible due to its protection level`

Which means the InternalsVisibleTo was not picked up.

I was expecting that Roslyn would automatically pick this up from the parsed project info, but I am now wondering if I have to enable some specific compilation option or to add some information manually?

I have looked around but I cannot find a similar question or an answer, unless I am missing something. I can give some more information if required. Thanks!

Comment: Often the problem here is that the options for the public key don't line up exactly with what is specified in the `InternalsVisibleTo`

Comment: Thanks, I agree that must be it. I think I found why this is happening in my case, will test it later and report.

Answer (score 0):

`InternalsVisibleTo` requires matching the public key used for signing the other assembly exactly (or no public key in case of unsigned assembly).
Double check you are providing either that correct key and the correct assembly name including the namespace.

Particularly, here, you are interested to the full public key, and not the public key token.

For more information and how to extract the public key for this purpose, please have a look at [InternalsVisibleToAttribute Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute?view=netcore-3.1).